# aps.net C# Renomear nome de uma imagem

Tags: c#, asp.net

tenho uma imagem numa pasta e queria mudar-lhe o nome apenas
alguem me consegue ajudar 
obrigado

exemplo:
nomeoriginal.jpg

passava para:
nomepretendido.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o **[`System.IO.File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)**

```
System.IO.File.Move("nomeoriginal.jpg", "nomepretendido.jpg");
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Lembrando que os parâmetros devem ser o **caminho completo** dos arquivos, não apenas o nome.

Comment: Bem observado @jbueno

Comment: obrigado funcionou muito bem

Comment: @Luisoliveira Você pode marcar essa resposta como correta marcando o **✓** logo abaixo das setas para votar...

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma segura para se fazer isto é fazer uma cópia da sua imagem de origem, para sua imagem de destino já com o nome que pretende usar na imagem de origem.
Por exemplo:

```
private void copyimage()
    {
        //Caminho padrão para as imagens.(Mude para o diretório aonde suas imagens estão armazenadas).
        string sCaminho = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\PastaImagens\";

        //Imagem de origem.
        string sImgOrigem = sCaminho + "NomeImgOrigem.jpg";

        //Imagem com novo nome.
        string sImgDestino = sCaminho + "NomeImgDestino.jpg";

        //Copia a imagem para mesma pasta, porém com o nome diferente.
        File.Copy(sImgOrigem, sImgDestino);

        //Se tudo deu certo, deleta a imagem de origem.
        File.Delete(sImgOrigem);
    }
```

Caso tenha dado certo, ao final excluímos nossa imagem de origem. Isso da uma segurança maior para não perdemos a imagem por algum outro problema, principalmente quando utilizamos isso em um loop.

Answer (score -1):

`insira o código aqui`    using System.IO;

```
namespace RenomeandoNomesDasFotos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Directory.Move("C:\Imagens\foto.png", "C:\Imagens\fotoRenomeada.png");
        }
    }
}
```